# DXA with Angular JS

Tags: dxa

Is it possible to use DXA with Angular JS? We want Angular for benefits of responsiveness and performance. Where as DXA for the reasons like ready to use modules for SmartTarget and XPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXA is currently built as an MVC web application for Java and ASP.NET.

While you can use it, and its concepts with Angular JS, you will currently have to figure all this out yourself as we haven't done anything for Angular JS support yet.

Angular and support for other client side frameworks is on the backlog, but it doesn't have a planned delivery date right now unfortunately.